# How to split all terms in a list in half?

Tags: python, list, split

I need to split a string into a list, and then split all terms of that list. I've been trying to make a function for this, but I can't find out how. I'm using this function to split the strings in half:

```
def split_case(string):
    length_string = len(string)
    first_length = round(length_string / 2)
    first_half = string[0:first_length]
    second_half = string[first_length:]
    return [first_half, second_half]
```

And I need to make something like this:

```
def split_all(string,runs):
    ...
    return split_up
```

And the output would look like this:

```
>>>print(split_all("Hello World!",1)
>>>["Hello ", "World!"]
```

And the 'runs' argument is how many times the string is split up, so one is half, two is quarter, three is eighth, four is sixteenth, and so on.

```
>>>print(split_all("Spam",2)
>>>["S","p","a","m"]
```

Or

```
>>>print(split_all("Hello World, Again!",3)
>>>["He", "llo", " W", "orl", "d,", " A", "ga", "in!"]
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Convert your first function to a one liner: `def split_str(string): return string[:len(string)//2], string[len(string)//2:]`

Comment: What is the semantic of your wanted output? cut each word in a half? if uneven, should the first or second part of the word be the longer ones or make a third element?

Comment: Okay, so you have a function that can cut a string in half. You want to cut all your strings in half, a certain number of times. You know how many times to do that. What exactly is the problem? Is it, for example, with applying "cut string in half" to all of the existing pieces?

Comment: Also, just to make sure - do you care about word boundaries? What should the output be for `split_all("extremelylongword short", 1)`, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you want to do when splitting a string of an odd length, e.g. does `split_case('hello')` return `['hel', 'lo']` or `['he', 'llo']`?

Here's a possible solution with a keyword argument that determines this behaviour:

```
def split_case(string, first_half_longer=True):
    string_length = len(string)
    split_length = string_length // 2
    if (string_length % 2 != 0) and first_half_longer:
        split_length += 1
    return [string[:split_length], string[split_length:]]


def split_all(string, runs, first_half_longer=True):
    original_string_list = [string]
    new_string_list = []
    for run in range(runs):
        for i in original_string_list:
            new_string_list.extend(split_case(i, first_half_longer))
        original_string_list = new_string_list
        new_string_list = []

    return original_string_list


string = "Hello World, Again!"

print(split_all(string, 3, True))
print(split_all(string, 3, False))
```

Output:

```
['Hel', 'lo', ' Wo', 'rl', 'd, ', 'Ag', 'ai', 'n!']
['He', 'll', 'o ', 'Wor', 'ld', ', A', 'ga', 'in!']
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't really bothered about what part of the string is longer, but this one gives me the choice; which is cool!

Comment: @Pomegranates-And-Python As you don't have voting privilege yet, it's [good practice to accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) you're going to use, especially when a number of people took the time to propose solutions to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can call recursively to split your string:

```
def split_str(args, runs=1):
    if not runs:
        return [args]
    else:
        runs -= 1
        h = len(args)//2
        beginning = args[:h]
        remaining = args[h:]
        return split_str(beginning, runs) + split_str(remaining, runs)
```

Output:

```
>>> split_str('Hello World!', 1)
>>> ['Hello ', 'World!']
>>> split_str('Hello World!', 2)
>>> ['Hel', 'lo ', 'Wor', 'ld!']
>>> split_str('spam', 2)
>>> ['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']
```

Answer (score 0):

A method with calculating how many the substring first, then accumulate them all.

```
def split_case(str, runs):
    l = len(str)
    res = []

    splitCnt = 2 ** runs
    if splitCnt >= l:
        splitCnt = l

    if (l % splitCnt == 0):
        runLen = l / splitCnt
    else:
        runLen = l / splitCnt + 1

    for i in range(0, l, runLen):
        res.append(str[i:i+runLen])

    return res

print(split_case("hello word", 2))
```

Output:

```
['hel', 'lo ', 'wor', 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

The short method using [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/textwrap.html?highlight=textwrap#textwrap.wrap)

```py
import textwrap

def split_all(string, n):
    return textwrap.wrap(string, int(len(string) / 2 ** n + 1))

print(split_all("Hello World, Again!",2))
# ['Hello', 'World', ', Aga', 'in!']
print(split_all("Hello World, Again!",3))
# ['Hel', 'lo ', 'Wor', 'ld,', 'Aga', 'in!']
```